# Why isn't my jQuery .Change being triggered?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I was playing with this last night and this morning a bit. On my WordPress site, I added a dropdown to a page to allow a user to select a podcast subscribe method (exactly like TWiT.tv's method).

In the page editor I have the following code.

```
<select id="subscribe-dropdown"><option value="0">Subscribe to Show</option>
    <option value="itms://mikewills.me/blog/category/show/bizdevtalk/feed/">iTunes</option>
    <option value="http://fusion.google.com/add?feedurl=http%3A//mikewills.me/blog/category/show/bizdevtalk/feed/">Google</option>
    <option value="winamp://Podcast/Subscribe?url=pcast://mikewills.me/blog/category/show/bizdevtalk/feed/">Winamp</option>
    <option value="zune://subscribe/?BizDevTalk=http://mikewills.me/blog/category/show/bizdevtalk/feed/">Zune</option>
    <option value="pcast://mikewills.me/blog/category/show/bizdevtalk/feed/">Other podcast clients (pcast:// compatible)</option>
    <option value="http://mikewills.me/blog/category/show/bizdevtalk/feed/">RSS</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $("#subscribe-dropdown").change(function() {
    if ($("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val() != "0"){
      window.open($("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val());
    };
  });
});
</script>
```

Since it is publicly accessible, the page can be found at http://mikewills.me/podcastmike/bizdevtalk/.

However the `.change()` isn't being triggered when I run it in debug. Is this a WordPress page issue or is something not quite set right?

Comment: Are you testing on IE ? Sometimes IE does not see the `change` event

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome either.

Comment: There is an error loading jQuery - `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function`. This happens on line 162 which is where this code is called.

Comment: No, I am testing in Firefox and Chrome. I believe Firefox is the latest version.

Comment: Works here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Ljxdv/ the only thing I do slightly different is to enclose the code in `$(document).ready()` function - try that

Comment: @mrtsherman I did not see that. I'll have to look at that first then.

Comment: Works here on chrome 16 : http://jsfiddle.net/xJUde/

Comment: I made a simple test on a non-wordpress page and the change event does occur. I did get a message that pop-ups were blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `jQuery` in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery("#subscribe-dropdown").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val() != "0"){
      window.open(jQuery("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val());
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: This is my first time dealing with that before. This was the problem.

Comment: if you check http://mikewills.me/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1, you'll see there's a call to `jQuery.noConflict();` there.

Comment: I guess I missed that and if I did see it, I didn't know what it did because I have never had to deal with that before. Thanks for the help. I have it working now.

Comment: Good question. I do wish I could mark them all as the answer. Since they all basically said the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#subscribe-dropdown").change(function() {
        if ($("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val() != "0") {
          window.open($("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val());
        };
    });
});
```

---

Or alternatively, wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { /** your code in here **/ });`

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

I have tested your code on `jsFiddle` and the event gets triggered.

So i think its a conflict with another javascript library.

You can change `$` to `jQuery` to make sure that its get handled by jQuery.

#### Sample

```
jQuery(function () {
  jQuery("#subscribe-dropdown").change(function() {
    if (jQuery("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val() != "0"){
      window.open(jQuery("#subscribe-dropdown option:selected").val());
    };
  });
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/52GmW/1/)**
- [jQuery - jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)