# How to remove select options and add new options with jQuery by class name

Tags: jquery, wordpress, class, html-select

I'm working with Wordpress and I've written a plugin which loads a jQuery source file.
My Website has a dropdown list and the HTML code looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="http://siradjov.anex.at/playground/">
    <div class="form-inner">   
       <div class="listing-search-main">
            <input type="text" class="listing-search-text text" name="s" title="Coach House, Golf Course, Water View, etc" value="unique">
            <input type="submit" class="listing-search-submit btn btn-large btn-primary" name="search-submit" value="Search">
            </div><!-- .listing-search-main -->

       <div class="listing-search-details">
           <div class="listing-search-field listing-search-field-select listing-search-field-status">
           <select class="listing-search-status select" name="status">
              <option value="">Status</option>
              <option value="sale">Sales</option>
              <option value="rent">Rentals</option>
              <option value="foreclosure">Foreclosure</option>
           </select>

      <div class="listing-search-advanced " style="display: block;">
          <div class="listing-search-field listing-search-field-select listing-search-field-min">
           <select class="listing-search-min select" name="min">
              <option value="">Price (min)</option>
              <option value="100000">100.000</option>
              <option value="200000">200.000</option>
              <option value="300000">300.000</option>
              <option value="400000">400.000</option>
           </select>
```

So it the select tag doesn't have an id and I am not allowed add an id because it is dynamically generated. Thus the only way I can select it is by **class name**.

Now I want remove all the options in the dropdown box and insert other options into it.

This is what I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".listing-search-min select[name='min']")
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="whatever">text</option>')
    .val('whatever');
});
```

I'm not sure but I think there is a mistake a make by giving the wrong class name.

Comment: The most obviously visible problem with your code is that your selector, `".listing-search-min select[name='min']"`, doesn't match the element you're trying to select. From your answer, it's clear that wasn't the only problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this if you want to update as per your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // pass the $ as arg in the callback
   var $select = $(".listing-search-min.select[name='min']");
   $select 
   .find('option')
   .remove();

   $select 
   .append('<option value="whatever">text</option>');
});
```

---

Issues with your code:

```
$(".listing-search-min select[name='min']") // this selector is wrong due to space
.find('option')
.remove()
.end() // when you use end it get back to selector again and in your case your selector was "option" not the select
.append('<option value="whatever">text</option>') // you are appending an option here with values so
.val('whatever'); // you dont need to set/select the value here
```

Comment: YES: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".listing-search-min select[name='min']")
                       ^------- Extra space
```

supposed to be

```
 $(".listing-search-min.select[name='min']")
```

If you are trying to use the select element instead of the class it is supposed to be

```
 $("select[name='min'].listing-search-min")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have 1 select with a name attribute of 'min'... try this:

```
// remove all the options
$("select[name='min']").html("");

// add something new
var tOpt = "<option value='1'>1.0</option>";
$("select[name='min']").html(tOpt);
```

you can make tOpt some string containing all the items you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='min'].listing-search-min").html('<option value="whatever">text</option>').val('whatever');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems like I am using jQuery in noConflict mode and I tried the suggestion in this post [Why isn't my jQuery .Change being triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730904/why-isnt-my-jquery-change-being-triggered).

Now this code works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var $select = jQuery(".listing-search-min.select[name='min']");
 $select.find('option').remove();

 $select.append('<option value="whatever">text</option>');
});
```

All I have to do is use jQuery instead $.

**Thank you for all your help! Appreciate it!**

Comment: you have not seen my updated answer that would do the same as well and BTW this is the answer which i posted though.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("select[name='min']").html(""); //delete everything
 $("select[name='min']").append("<option value="whatever">text</option>");//add the new option
```